# How to use procedure within package in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, package

How to create a Package with Procedure in it?  Procedure will take designation and incentive as input and update the employee salary by adding the incentive for the given designation. Display the number of employee records that have got updated, e.g. ‘3 employee record(s) are updated’.
I have a table EMPLOYEE, with EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, SALARY and DESIGNATION.
The given Functional Requirements are:

```
Package name as  EMP_DESIGNATION, and
Procedure signature:
EMP_DETAILS(design employee.designation%TYPE, incentive number);
```

The code which I tried is -

```
set serveroutput on;
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE EMP_DESIGNATION AS
 PROCEDURE EMP_DETAILS(
design employee.designation%TYPE,
incentive NUMBER) IS
BEGIN
UPDATE employee SET employee.salary = employee.salary + incentive
WHERE employee.designation = design;
dbms_output.put_line(SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' employee record(s) are updated');
END EMP_DESIGNATION;
END;
/
```

The output is-

```
Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors.
BEGIN
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04063: package body "P10017.EMP_DESIGNATION" has errors
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called:
"P10017.EMP_DESIGNATION"
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

How to solve this error? Please help. Thank you in advance.
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: To find out how many rows are affected by DML statements, you check the value of SQL%ROWCOUNT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a package **specification** first, then its **body**. Something like this:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE emp_designation
  2  AS
  3     PROCEDURE emp_details (design employee.designation%TYPE, incentive NUMBER);
  4  END emp_designation;
  5  /

Package created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY emp_designation
  2  AS
  3     PROCEDURE emp_details (design employee.designation%TYPE, incentive NUMBER)
  4     IS
  5     BEGIN
  6        UPDATE employee
  7           SET employee.salary = employee.salary + incentive
  8         WHERE employee.designation = design;
  9
 10        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
 11           SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' employee record(s) are updated');
 12     END emp_details;
 13  END emp_designation;
 14  /

Package body created.

SQL>
```

Comment: After making the changes still the code raised error, which I have mentioned, by editing it in the question above.

Comment: Changes you did were incorrect. Look again at my code. You can't END the package body first, and then END the procedure.

Comment: Oh so I should not end the begin, as we are ending both the procedure and package?

Comment: You **MUST** end everything that began, but you must pay attention to what you're ending.